# IIS 8.5 cutting off HTTP-POST with JSON data to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, iis

I am hosting an ASP.NET Web Api on WinSrv 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.

The web api has one action in a controller that receives a json object - for the sake of discussion it looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, "api/action"]
ResponseModel GetIt(RequestModel requestData)
```

It works great except when I try to post data that's large.  For example, when I try to post 8Mb of json (it includes base64 encoded image files).

How it fails is rather interesting.  Basically, the action is called but model (RequestModel) is missing certain key properties.  Leading me to believe that there's an error deserializing the object but I dont' see that.  My Web API action immediately throws an exception because it's getting a few key null values.

I turned on FailedRequestTracking in IIS and I see the following:

> The request comes in with these headers:
>
> - Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
> - Connection: Keep-Alive
> - Content-Length: 12262199
> - Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> - Accept: application/json
> - Expect: 100-continue

In this case the object is ~12MB.  The various handler matching starts and eventually IIS settles on the `ManagedPipelineHandler` to handle the request.  It reads 16,384 bytes, then reads 16,384 bytes again, then reads 16,384 bytes one final time and you see the `NOTIFY_MODULE_COMPLETION` entry.

I see the `AspNetHttpHandlerEnter` event and after setting up the response header I see the 500 error from my exception.  `MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS`

Does anyone know why the `ManagedPipelineHandler` is only reading 48K?  I need to be able to post up to 25Mb of data.